# Can CSS file loading be deferred via http LINK header and does that block rendering

Tags: php, css, http, browser, cross-browser

If we use the [http link header](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader) to provide a link to a CSS file very early on what browsers would NOT download this link and are there any browsers for which a CSS file provided this way would block rendering the "above the fold content"?

This would be the HTTP header:

```
Link: <style.css>; rel="stylesheet"
```

This an untested PHP implementation of the same thing (if one does not configure apache to do it like hinted at in the link above):

```
<?php
header('Link: <style.css>; rel="stylesheet"');
?>
```

**Question:** cross browser compatibility and render blocking behavior

Comment: 14 views in a month - let's have a bounty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies in advance that my response is not directly in reference to use of the http Link header. If the objective is to try and load non-critical CSS asynchronously(in the background without blocking page rendering), this can be achieved with JavaScript. See the [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) project for some good documentation and examples.

Normally, all CSS files included in a standard way(e.g. `<link href="path/to/mystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">`) do in fact block page rendering until ALL stylesheets have finished loading. This is for good performance reasons by browsers in order to prevent multiple re-layouts and re-paints when loading a page after each stylesheet finishes loading.

The idea with this solution is basically to alter the media type for the non-critical stylesheet(s) to something the browser will see as unimportant for page rendering(e.g. "only x"), and then manually switch the media type back to the standard "all" (or other value as needed), which is likely after then resource is finished loading, but could be further deferred if desired based on your use case.

This method is pretty reliable as long as you only need to to support relatively modern browsers. I've used it in production for content thats had millions of pageviews. You may be able to implement something similar using the Link header but you'd still need some client side script in place to detect when the resource finished loading and to switch the media type back to "all".

Comment: Actually I already do that. The question is about speed. If I provide a LINK to the .css file by HTTP and the browser would instantly start downloading that in parallel to the page that will later request the same thing asynchronously I'd count on the browser realizing "oh I'm already downloading that" - or being done with it already. If the HTTP LINK was non render blocking that might well be beneficial. If it would be render blocking it would be counterproductive. I can't belive there is no information on-line but I don't have the time to test it.

Comment: If you configured the Link header with a non-blocking `media` attribute value(e.g. "only x") as mentioned it would indeed be non-blocking to page rendering.  See 5.4 "Target Attributes" of the RFC(http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988.txt) for setting the media type.  Then you would just need to detect load from the client side and change the media type back to a value the browser will use for rendering after the .css file finishes loading(e.g. "all")

Comment: Indeed, that might do it. I didn't realize media would be applicable in this. Probably edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if you can do that with a `header()` function, but non-blocking css can be done with JavaScript - see this paste: http://pastebin.com/TYcnb99m

It uses local storage as cache for loaded css files and is non-blocking.

Some more links:

- https://gist.github.com/scottjehl/87176715419617ae6994
- https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already doing non-blocking CSS. The question asked specifically about the HTTP header Link. None of the material in your post is even related to that. I do extend warm greetings to the person writing it but downvote the answer because of that mismatch.

Comment: Well, I definitely understood the question. My response was based on the [lack of browser support](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-without-html/) and the fact that this is a [proposed standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988). Considering all of the above, plus the fact that this technique adds a reasonable amount of time to figure out by newcomers / new-hires, I wouldn't recommend doing that.